# How to return user details in response after login in django rest_framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

Hi I am beginner in Django Here I want user email and name in response after user login using api. Thanks in advance for your help.

models.py 
I want user email and user name in response only getting auth token in response

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        if not password:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a password')

        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(email,password)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

serializers.py
I want user email and user name in response only getting auth token in response

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(
            required=True,
            validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
            )
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'name')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'min_length': 6}}

        def create(self, validated_data):
            user = User.objects.create_user('name',validated_data['email'],
                validated_data['password'],)
            return user

class AuthTokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    email = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(
        style = {'input_type':'password'},
        trim_whitespace = False
    )

    def validate(self, attrs):

        email = attrs.get('email')
        password = attrs.get('password')

        user = authenticate(
            request = self.context.get('request'),
            username = email,
            password = password
        )

        if not user:

            msg = _('Unable to authenticate with provided crenditial')
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code = 'authorization')

        attrs['user'] = user

        return attrs
```

urls.py
I want user email and user name in response only getting auth token in response

```
path('api/login/',views.CreateTokenView.as_view(),name='token'),
```

View file for creating view and I dont now how to return user from Auth token. I want user email and user name in response only getting auth token in response
views.py

```
class UserCreate(APIView):
    """
    Creates the user.
    """

    def post(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
                json = serializer.data
                json['token'] = token.key
                return Response(json, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class CreateTokenView(ObtainAuthToken):

    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer
    renderer_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES



    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(CreateTokenView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        token = Token.objects.get(key=response.data['token'])
        return Response({'token': token.key})
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you can do is maybe once you recieve a valid token for the user, you could query for the user using the user's email from the request data.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super(CreateTokenView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
    token = Token.objects.get(key=response.data['token'])
    user_email = request.data.get('email', None)
    user = User.objects.get(email=user_email)
    return Response({'name': user.name, 'email': user.email, 'token': token.key})
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I ended up searching for this.
For the new comers:

There's an example on Django REST Framework, available [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CustomAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data,
                                       context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({
            'token': token.key,
            'user_id': user.pk,
            'email': user.email
        })
```